# How can i add event listener to subfolders after opening main directory in the website folder

Tags: javascript, html

I have linked a folder from my root folder where website index page is located. Onclick of button opens the folder that has sub folders, i'm stack here, i would like when user clicks on subfolder the files in the subfolder are loaded to select element as options.
[HOW IT LOOKS ON BROWSER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YScMu.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Datafiles</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="loadmfiles" onclick = "window.location.href = 'midifiles'">Sample files</button>
    <select id = "playlist_container"></select>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Once you use `location.href`, unless its not a hashtag, all scope is lost from current file and the new file has the new scope

Comment: Is there a simpler way that can solve that, please?

Comment: Seems you are just going to the server side file structure. I see nothing in your screenshot where you'd expect different behavior